# multiple reading from folder

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to read all files from the folder and write to buffer. All files have the same name except the last portion (file_0000.mdf, file_0001.mdf,....file_9999.mdf). How i can read all the files?  testFolder contains all the files. If i go with for_loop,it will start with 0 but my test_files start from 0000 and so on.  Also, i need file size of each individual test file. My logic is wrong, but i do not know how to fix it. Some updated code is also given below the first approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main(){

std::string path="C:\\testFolder\\";
std::string constName="file_";
std::string lastName = ".mdf";
std::fstream InputStream;
std::string fileWithPath;

for (int i=0; i <9999;i++){

    fileWithPath=path+constName+std::to_string(static_cast<long long> 
    (i)+lastName;
     InputStream.open(fileWithPath,std::ios::binary);
     long InputFileSize= InputStream.tellg();
    }

  return 0;
  }
```

Short update by using boost/filesystem. Need comments on this approach.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

std::string SourceFolder="C:\\testFolder\\";
path mDirectory(SourceFolder);

std::cout<<"Directory includes the following files"
if(is_directory(mDirectory)){
for(auto testFile=mDirectory.begin();testFile!=mDirectory.end();testFile++){
    std::cout<< testFile->string()<<std::endline;   
}
```

Comment: You call `fstream::open` without closing. That won't work. Regarding formatting the number check `std::stringstream`, `setfill` and `setw`. If you can use C++17, then take a look at [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator).

Comment: Please don't edit a question in a way so that existing answers don't make sense.  You can open another question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Plain integers doesn't have leading zeros. To get leading zeros you need to use some other way of formatting your file-names. For example by using [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and standard [I/O manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) like `std::setw` and `std::setfill`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << path << constName << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << i << lastName;
fileWithPath = oss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()` functions scanning the files in the directory using wildcard, i.e. "C:\Data\file_???.mdf".
Returned [WIN32_FIND_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_win32_find_dataa) will contain also a file size.

Take a look on the complete example "[Listing the Files in a Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory)".

Once a file is listed, you may read its content with `ifstream` as usually.